# Error send Data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I develop this code to send data, x & y coordinates in WP7 screen to the PC server, but its not work, but debugger its work fine and I am sure my code is right.
there is no error showing
this code for WP7 client side

```
TransformGroup transformG;
    TranslateTransform translation;
    double DeltaX, DeltaY;

    private Socket client_socket;
    private delegate void mydelegate(byte[] buffer);
    private delegate void ShowMessagedelegate(string MSG);
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(MainPage_ManipulationDelta);
        transformG = new TransformGroup();
        translation = new TranslateTransform();
        transformG.Children.Add(translation);
    }
    void MainPage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {

        DeltaX = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        DeltaY = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;

    }
    void StartSending()
    {
            try
            {
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DeltaX.ToString()+"/"+DeltaY.ToString());
                socketEventArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                client_socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArgs);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
    }


    void Conncet(string IP_Address)
    {

        client_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
        {
            RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP_Address), 4532)
        };
        socketEventArg.Completed += OnConncetCompleted;
        client_socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
    }





    private void ConnectBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Conncet(IPAddress_TXT.Text);
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartSending));
    }
```

and this code for Server side

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);
public Int32 pX, pY;
Socket SenderSocket;
void StartReceiving()
    {
        byte[] response = new byte[10000];
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.Completed += OnReceiveCompleted;
        socketEventArg.SetBuffer(response, 0, response.Length);
        SenderSocket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
    }

    void OnReceiveCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new mydelegate(ModifCursorPos), e.Buffer);
        this.BeginInvoke(new mydelegate(ModifCursorPos), e.Buffer);
    }
    private void ModifCursorPos(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            string chaine = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            string[] pos = chaine.Split('/');

                pX = Convert.ToInt32(pos[0]);
                pY = Convert.ToInt32(pos[1]);
                //posX.Text = pX.ToString();
                //posY.Text = pY.ToString();

            ms.Close();

            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + pX, Cursor.Position.Y + pY);
            posX.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();//try to get X in textbox
            posY.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();//try to get Y in textbox
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            StartReceiving();
        }
    }
```

I don't know why its not send the data, or maybe don't receive it
plz help
and thanks

Comment: `catch (Exception) { }` could easily be masking your problems. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DeltaX.ToString()+"/"+DeltaY.ToString());
            socketEventArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            client_socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
```

this would keep hide your Exception if you have one so try changing this to

```
        try
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DeltaX.ToString()+"/"+DeltaY.ToString());
            socketEventArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            client_socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.Write(e.Tostring()); }
```

This will help figure out what is causing the problem and then if you get an exception post it up here and we can help you more

also same thing for this one
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            string chaine = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            string[] pos = chaine.Split('/');

```
            pX = Convert.ToInt32(pos[0]);
            pY = Convert.ToInt32(pos[1]);
            //posX.Text = pX.ToString();
            //posY.Text = pY.ToString();

        ms.Close();

        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + pX, Cursor.Position.Y + pY);
        posX.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();//try to get X in textbox
        posY.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();//try to get Y in textbox
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
```

Comment: Ok I add Exception and it show me eroor, I create an video for it
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7N0Ls__qm0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: same here sorry, now its narrowed down maybe someone can help you but im not sure whats causing it.  if you could upvote this answer since i did help you narrow the problem down though.